# MySQL joining tables and counting the number of rows in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I know the below SQL statement is completely wrong but I hope it gives an example of what I want to do. I have a users table, a payments (user payments not order payments) table and an orders table. I want to select 10 random users who have made 6 or more payments to us, who have not made any orders yet.

In the payments table there are multiple rows for each user for each payment they have made. In the orders table it's the same, but it contains completed and uncompleted orders and i'm looking for users who don't have any completed orders so `o.order_status` must be `0` for ALL orders in the orders table.

I hope that makes sense and if you need any more info let me know and i'll update the post. Appreciate the help.

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(p.id) as payment_count, COUNT(o.id) as order_count
                    FROM users as u
                    INNER JOIN payments as p
                    ON u.id = p.user_id
                    INNER JOIN orders as o
                    ON u.id = o.user_id
                    WHERE o.order_status = 0
                    AND COUNT(p.id) > 6
                    AND COUNT(o.id) = 0
                    ORDER BY RAND()
                    LIMIT 10
```

Comment: `HAVING` is a useful option for `COUNT(column)>#` - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp  And `GROUP BY` is required for `COUNT()` but can cause difficulties with `SELECT *` if done incorrectly.

Comment: It would speed things up if you pasted the SQL DDL for your tables, and some INSERT statements that populated those tables with a little representative data.

Comment: A few reading for you about [SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually quite close with your query. As mentioned by others, use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` and you're most of the way there. In addition, outer-join to *orders* and include the 'order_status = 0' check in the join to help accomplish the 'no orders with status of zero' requirement. The result:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    COUNT(p.id) as payment_count, 
    COUNT(o.id) as order_count
FROM users as u
    INNER JOIN payments as p
        ON u.id = p.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders as o
        ON u.id = o.user_id
            AND o.order_status = 0
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING COUNT(p.id) >= 6
    AND COUNT(o.id) = 0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

You'll have to include other columns from the *users* table in the `GROUP BY` if you want to include them in the `SELECT`. Also, it's probably just an oversight, but you'll want `>= 6` (not `> 6`) for the first part of the `HAVING` clause too.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. Although it was down to my bad coding, i'm actually looking for `o.order_status = 1` then ensuring the count is `0` so that there are no completed orders.

Answer (score 1):

Without doing a deep dive into your code, to filter by COUNT or the result of any aggregate function, you need to use a HAVING clause.

It looks like you are also lacking GROUP BY clauses.  I would read up on HAVING and GROUP BY as a first step.